# How to execute test based on environment conditions?

Tags: junit, java-8, java-11

I have unit tests which refer to derby drivers, as everyone knows java8 has different derby drivers and java11 has different. I want my test to refer to correct drivers based on the java version.
OR
I can create two projects, one has derby drivers supporting java11 and one supporting java8. I want something like this, if I have java11 running then the java8 unit tests should be ignored and vice versa.

Can I design such envirionment specific unit tests? If yes can you give me an idea?

Comment: multi-release jar.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what do I have to do for multi-realease.jar

Comment: exactly is something you will need to figure out, I guess. That was a hint towards a possible solution